# Files are not getting included. Images CSS URL's not working after migrating server code to local

Tags: drupal-7, migration, drupal-theming, drupal-cache

I have downloaded drupal code and database from server. I am trying setup local environment, I am unable to include Images and Css's. On server its working fine but when I run the drupal setup on local gives error on including files.

Am using Xampp.

Let me know how can adjust the correct path.

I have tried all the options possible by googling for 3-4 hours but there is no solution that worked....

Path getting now :

http://localhost:8080/sites/all/themes/MYTHEMEFOLDER/assets/styles/new.css

http://localhost:8080/sites/all/themes/MYTHEMEFOLDER/assets/media/images/logo/logo.png

Path expected :

http://localhost:8080/drupalTestSite/sites/all/themes/MYTHEMEFOLDER/assets/styles/new.css

http://localhost:8080/drupalTestSite/sites/all/themes/MYTHEMEFOLDER/assets/media/images/logo/logo.png

Comment: If you were using MAMP, I'd check to make sure your Document root: was set correctly.

Comment: Yes, its correct. Other CSS ,Image are getting loaded properly. only 7-8 Images and 2-3 CSS has path problem.

Comment: Are your permissions correct on those directories and files? Also a followup,when you say 'getting error' are you talking about your web browser console? Or Drupal actually printing an error to the screen?

Comment: all permissions are there. Its on browser console.